# Virtualbox does not create snapshots from remote virtual disks

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-shares

I have the exact same image in 2 locations:

a) A local drive
b) A network drive

I add the image to the VM, create a snapshot and immediately see a small file (e.g. `{e7883218-ea9e-4146-8fbf-54e31b9411ce}.vdi` appear in the Snapshots dir of the VM. Starting the VM makes that file grow, while the original image is untouched as expected and all seems well in the world.

Adding an image from a network location (a samba share on my NAS) and taking a snapshot, no such sequence of events occurs. There is no snapshot taken and when booted, the original image is modified in place, on the network.

**I would very much like to boot from the network, while maintaining snapshots locally.**

Is this a bug? A setting I missed? Some misconfiguration?
My google fu has failed me miserably as every search query returns unrelated results.

Keep in mind the distinction is *local vs network drive*, not drive where VM is located vs not. If the drive is local, even if it's not the same as where the VM is located, it will still correctly make snapshots.

Edit: I tried being clever and creating a symlink from the network share to my local machine, then adding that. It did not work. :)

Edit2: Log says the following when trying to create a snapshot:
`ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={300763af-5d6b-46e6-aa96-273eac15538a} aComponent={MachineWrap} aText={The machine is not mutable (state is PoweredOff)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0`

Edit3: Creating via CLI says Snapshot taken and gives some UUID, with no error, but there is no snapshot (log still has the error).

VBox v7.0.8 btw.

Comment: ***"There is no snapshot taken"*** when going to Snapshots on the VM it's empty?

Comment: Entirely and sadly @YisroelTech. (Well it does put some random `.nvram` file in there, but no snapshot.)

Comment: @martixy - You should edit your question to clarify it instead of submitting a comment

Comment: What are the logs saying? Try to take the snapshot and then copy/check the log ***VBoxSVC.log*** from `%UserProfile%\.VirtualBox` folder (on Windows)

Comment: Interesting. So far vbox has been more than happy to yell at me for every error, so it did not occur to me to look for the logs. For some reason this one is silently ignored. It's not often you run into a situation where google returns less than 20 results. :) None of them are helpful either.

Comment: Are you sure this error is from when (trying to be) creating the snapshot? It's off but the state issue doesn't make sense to be related (as being Powered Off  is the perfect state for a snapshot.)

Comment: Yes. @YisroelTech

Comment: Another way to maybe get a better immediate error reading, try creating the snapshot from the command line utility, by running (open command prompt or change directory to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`) `VBoxManage snapshot <uuid|vmname> take <snapshot-name>` (e.g. `VBoxManage snapshot "My VM Name" take test_snapshots`)

Comment: I must admit, I have never been asked "Are you sure?" so many times before. Tho if you were looking for an error in the terminal, none appears. Just says "Snapshot taken". But we do get the same error in the log file.

Comment: "Snapshot created" or "Snapshot taken"? (Details matter very much when trying to figure out an issue.) And does it show a UUID after that?

Comment: "Snapshot taken". And yes.

Comment: Please add the additional info to the question instead of (only) having them in the comments. Maybe it's some config issue with the particular machine you have there. Have you tried creating a new VM from fresh on the network drive and do a snapshot on it?

Comment: I had not tried that. **But that seems to resolve the problem.** Also, I'm not sure what info you're talking about. I included everything that's not just me confirming things already said. But thank you for the help. Never would have guess that recreating the machine would have something to do with it, given that I can mix and match local vdis with ease. Perhaps it really is a bug?

Comment: I was talking about the info like that you tried creating it in CLI and it said Snapshot taken, or that creating it from fresh does work. While they are answers to my picking your brain... they're relevant details to your question for someone to be able to try to answer it, so always Edit them in to your question.

Comment: I am not sure what you really mean by "mix and match local VDIs", my suspicion that something was wrong with that VM in the first place (some config change in it that isn't correct) and therefore the snapshots on it were having issues.

Comment: I mean I could boot up from local virtual disks from multiple drives (as I said in the question I was considering whether it wanted the vdi on the same drive as the VM, but that turned out to not be the case). And since you spoke of details mattering - note that it had a problem with snapshots from remote locations. It was perfectly happy creating a snapshot of any vdi on a local drive. As for the solution - does that not go in an answer? (Tho admittedly we still do not know the root cause.)

Comment: Not sure it's a real answer... With the new VM created, can you now "mix and match"? In the old VM machine, maybe you messed manually with the config to try to have the snapshots and VM/VDI on different locations?

Comment: I can, it seems. The manager is obnoxiously finicky with switching disks (if they're all named the same), but otherwise now there's no problem. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not sure what might be causing the issue (the error given seems not to really be related to anything about the snapshot, and in CLI the snapshot reports to be created, so it might not be an issue with "creating the snapshot" but the VM not knowing afterward that it exists.)

You can try with a fresh start by creating a new VM on the network drive and see if a snapshot from this new machine does work.

If it does, this will take away the blame from the local drive vs. network drive.

Comment: Yes, it seems recreating the VM fixed the issue. However one caveat: *but the VM not knowing afterward that it exists* - we had already established early on that no file is created. It is the first question you asked. So I suppose shotgun debugging wins the day once more…? 

Comment: I would disagree with the conclusion that no file is created. It might be created somewhere else (and you don't know where to check) and that might be caused by some config stuff in the old VM.